# Calculate data to an input field from 2 select fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to calculate 2 options from different selects in HTML and display the result in an input field. The first **select** will fill from a mysql database, the second **select** will fill with 1 option that is the pair of the first. I want to multiply them and display the result in the last input field. Here is an example:

The table of the database the field are "id product"-id quantity price type
[table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwR67.jpg)

Here is the result that i want: [to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNDK0.jpg)

When the user selects the quantity the corresponding value is going to be displayed to the next field.

After that in the last input field i want to calculate the previous selections

- the user can only select the quantity and not the price

I made a select with **php** and made an array which is converted to javascript array object

```
<?php
        $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT quantity,price FROM eb_products_price WHERE product_id = 20");
        $sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
$json_array = json_encode($result);
print_r($result);
```

With this code the only thing i can do is to display the quantity with a **foreach** 
BUT the price will remain the last one and it wont change while i change the quantity.

I found a way to display the correct price but with **javascript** here is the code

```
<script>
var arrayObjects = {"400":["0.8"],"300":["0.9"],"200":["0.95"],"100":["1.1"]}


function products() {
    var quantity= document.getElementById("quantity");
    var price= document.getElementById("price");
    var arrprice = quantity.options[quantity.selectedIndex].value;
    while (price.options.length) {
        price.remove(0);
    }
    var prices = arrayObjects[arrprice];
    if (prices) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            var price1 = new Option(prices[i], i);
            price.options.add(price1);

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the calculate function that work without the last part of code:

```
calculate = function()
{
    var quantity= document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    var price= document.getElementById('price').value; 
    var number = parseFloat(quantity)*parseFloat(price);
    var n = number.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('result').value = n
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a HTML-Element dynamically you need event Listeners like **onChange** example below:

```js
var arrayObjects = {"400":["0.8"],"300":["0.9"],"200":["0.95"],"100":["1.1"]}


function products() {
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var factor = document.getElementById("factor"); // added
    var price= document.getElementById("price");
    
    // Fill dropdown (quantity)
    while (quantity.options.length) { 
        quantity.remove(0);
    }

    // fill by key
    for( var quantity_key in arrayObjects ) { 
      var quantity_option = new Option(
        quantity_key,
        quantity_key
      );
      quantity.options.add(quantity_option);

    }
    
    // onChange-Listener
    quantity.onchange = () => {
      factor.value = arrayObjects[quantity.value];
      
      // look for factor by key in arrayObjects
      price.value = Math.round( 
        quantity.value *arrayObjects[quantity.value] 
      );
    };
}



products();
```

```html
<select id='quantity'></select>
KG
<input type='text' id='factor' readonly="readonly">
<input type='text' id='price' readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! i think this is what i want! one more question... how can i display inside the input with id="factor" the price value and not the quantity not the i want the select to be ex. <select id="quantity"><option>400</option></select> <input type="text" id="factor" value="0.8"> <input type="text" id="price" value="320">

Comment: Ah ups, sorry fixed it:

[original] factor.value = quantity.value;
[new] factor.value = arrayObjects[quantity.value];

Answer (score -1):

in javascript, to get the selected element (value) of a select, use :

```
var e = document.getElementById("quantity");
var quantity= e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```